# How to filter product list by custom attribute on category page of Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I made 3 tabs on category page, which are All Products, Online Products and Store Only Products.

All products display all products under this category.

I use

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

to do the job.

Online Products will display custom attribute (product_type) equals "Online Product"

Store Only Products will display custom attribute (product_type) equals "Store Only Product"

How can I create a block to display Online Products and Store Only Products under this category?

Comment: Are you asking how to display this attribute, or how to filter your product list by this attribute?

Comment: how to filter product list by this attribute

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to make a duplicate of the List block and add the filter you need.

*You May need to modify your attribute in the Magento admin area to "show in product listing" too.*

for example:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

this will use the List block to filter the collection for you, lets make a copy:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php
```

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Mylist.php
```

Now lets modify the Block to use our custom attribute, something like this should work (not tested)

Mylist.php

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Mylist extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
    /**
     * Retrieve loaded category collection
     *
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();

        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('my_attribute')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('my_attribute', array('eq' => '000001'))
        ;

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Now you simple use your new block:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_mylist" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Somehow doesn't work. Should I put `$this->_productCollection = $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('product_type')->addAttributeToFilter('product_type', array('eq' => 'Online Product'));` if my custom attribute is product_type

Comment: on errors, just not display. You can check on http://kkstores.net/index.php/test-category-1.html

Comment: can you change it to this: return parent::_getProductCollection(); this will just rule out any issue with finding the block.

Comment: by the way which magento version are you on?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I found out even I copy List.php and did not make any changes. When I call `{{block type="catalog/product_mylist" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}`, it shows nothing. So I think it may be file address problem. Do we need create XML file or other files to fix this?

Comment: No, if you copy to the local namespace it will be found just fine. Did you copy the folder structure correctly? You also need to make syure Capital letters for Directory names

Comment: which filter, do you mean the layered navigation filters? or the filter you are applying in the code?

Comment: filter in code.`$collection->addAttributeToSelect('product_type')->addAttributeToFilter('product_type', array('eq' => 'Online Product'));`

Comment: what happens does it just not filter at all? Is your attribute a normal varchar text attrbute?

Comment: Yes, it's just not filter. The attribute is a normal varchar text attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Never, but NEVER, create or modify a Magento CORE class. The answer is to implement your module, override the List block class and customize the method _getProductCollection.