# Show Sale product on category view page Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How can I get sale products(special price) on category view page.    Products must be from same category or sub-categories.    Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [Magento.se]

Comment: So what, Magento is also based on PHP. you don't need to be -1 for question.

Comment: Your question is not tagged PHP.

Comment: #Keyur Shah: thanks, I got solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way is to make a duplicate of the List block and add the filter you need.

You May need to modify your attribute in the Magento admin area to "show in product listing" too.

for example:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

this will use the List block to filter the collection for you, lets make a copy:

app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php
to

app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Mylist.php
Now lets modify the Block to use our custom attribute, something like this should work (not tested)

Mylist.php

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Mylist extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
    /**
     * Retrieve loaded category collection
     *
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();
        $todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
            0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
            1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
        ), 'left')
        ->addAttributeToSort('special_from_date', 'desc');

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Now you simple use your new block:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_mylist" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Thanks to(ref by): [How to filter product list by custom attribute on category page of Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441148/how-to-filter-product-list-by-custom-attribute-on-category-page-of-magento/16457095#16457095)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to edit `list.phtml` from

app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTHEME/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

**and write below code at starting of file**

`$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection()` // **Remember you have to comment this line**

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/advanced_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
->addMinimalPrice()
->addStoreFilter();

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($_productCollection);

$todayDate = date('m/d/y');
$tomorrow = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('y'));
$tomorrowDate = date('m/d/y', $tomorrow);

 $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');



 $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
    0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $tomorrowDate),
    1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
    ), 'left')
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
    array('finset' => $currentCategory->getId()))
;
```

***and comment this line***

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: No, its not working for me.  I have done category is anchor TRUE in admin.

Comment: normal product is display or not means without special price product?

Comment: its working my side please check you have any product for special price or not if not then please add 3-4 product check

Comment: please check my update answer for current category special price collection its working fine in my side

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in ****\***\***\**\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816

Comment: Please check my list.phtml from[version Magento 1.7] this http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/529081/list-phtml.html